# How to perform string validation & unit testing using google test in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, googletest

I am trying to write some string validation functions such as

- check whether **the string is NULL, Empty or have only spaces!**
- check whether **the string is alphanumeric or uppercase!**

I am only interested in strings with **lowercase alphabets from a-z.(VALID strings)** rest I want to block, so I have written the following functions:

```
std::string isEmpty(const std::string &input){
    // empty string
    if (NULL ==input || input=="\0" || !input.size())
        return "";
}
std::string isMalfunctioned(const std::string &input){
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i){
        // string is not a-z or alphanumeric or uppercase
        if ( input[i] < 'a' || input[i] > 'z'|| isalpha(input[i]) || isupper(input[i]) )
            return "";
    }
}
```

and from the main function, I am just calling myFunc() using a reference to the input string & it calls the validation function written above to notify a user of incoming invalid strings:

```
#include"myFunc.h"

std::string myFunc(const std::string & input){
    if( isEmpty(input)== "")
        std::cout<<"Empty input"<< std::endl;
    if( isMalfunctioned(input)== "")
        std::cout<<"malfunctioned input"<< std::endl;
    return input;
}
int main(){
    std::string input="1234";
    std::cout << myFunc(input)<< std::endl;
    return  0;
}
```

***My question:***

- First, I think my validation functions are not syntaticaly correct, since I am getting compile time errors as below, could anyone help in this regards?

---

```
mismatched types ‘const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_
Iterator, _Container>’ and ‘long int’

candidate: template<class _Iterator,
 class _Container> bool __gnu_cxx::operator==(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterat
or, _Container>&, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>&)
     operator==(const __normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>& __lhs,
```

- Second, I think, my validation functions are not fully covering my specifications. Any suggestion for it?
- Third, I have written some test cases using google test, but unable to interface with the above functionality, Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong & how to correct them? Also, any suggestion on refactoring the code is also welcomed!

---

```
#include "myfunc.h"
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(testbundle, EmptyString){
  ASSERT_EQ("", myfunc(""));
}

TEST(testbundle, Malfunctioned){
  ASSERT_EQ("", myfunc("ad34534654"));
  ASSERT_EQ("", myfunc("!$#sadasfd1"));
}

TEST(testbundle, LowerCase){
  ASSERT_EQ("abbsbdbbdbdb", myfunc("abbsbdbbdbdb"));
}
TEST(PreliminaryTest, UpperCaseString){
  ASSERT_EQ("", myfunc("ASDFFGGGHH"));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Comment: `isEmpty` and `isMalfunctioned` have undefined behavior because control flow may leave the function without returning anything. And it makes not sense for these functions to return another string.

Comment: A `std::string` instance can't ever be `NULL` or `nullptr`. You'll have an instance.

Comment: Please one question per question. Currently this is a bit too broad. And I dont really spot what line is the error from

Comment: @user463035818, currently, the compile-time error is in the function definition only. Since I am coming from a python background, I have a hard time fixing the syntax of my `isEmpty() & isMalfunctioned()` function's definition, that's the main pressing issue I have right now. If you could help me out in correcting the syntax adhering the requirements `1. check whether the string is NULL, Empty or have only spaces!` and `2. check whether the string is alphanumeric or uppercase!, I will take from there. Hope I was able to explain the issue.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, thanks, that's what I am trying to handle, the input could be anything, it's programmer responsibility to handle those cases, I am trying to handle such situations and notify the user that it's a wrong input! does my use case make sense, please suggest.

Comment: @VTT, thanks for point that out, if you could provide a way to do it, it would be helpful. I have written the desired validation required for my input strings.

Comment: @anu Do you come from Java environment by any chance? In C++ reference cannot be null. Reference is always bound to an existing object (note that pointers could be `NULL`, if you use them anywhere). Compiler error most likely comes from issue mentioned by VTT. And one more thing, your `isMalfunctioned` always return empty string, because `input[i] < 'a' || input[i] > 'z'|| isalpha(input[i])` is always true (you check if the character *is not lowercase character* **or** *is character*)